# Hierarchy of static properties in inherited class

Tags: php, inheritance

I want to define a static property in a class, and have each child class have its own value for that property.

Here is what I tried:

```
class A {
    static protected $v = "A";
    
    static public function getV() {
        return static::$v;
    }

    static public function setV($value) {
        static::$v = $value;
    }

}

class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

B::setV("B");

print_r(A::getV());
print_r(B::getV());
print_r(C::getV());
print_r("\n");

C::setV("C");

print_r(A::getV());
print_r(B::getV());
print_r(C::getV());
print_r("\n");
```

What I expected:

```
ABA // C::$v hasn't been initialized, so it holds the parent's value
ABC
```

What I got:

```
BBB
CCC
```

So, there is only one property available, and it's the parent's one.
To get what I expected, I had to redeclare and initialize my static property in the child classes:

```
class B extends A {
    static protected $v;
    static public function init() {
        self::$v = parent::$v;
    }
}
B::init();

class C extends A {
    static protected $v;
    static public function init() {
        self::$v = parent::$v;
    }
}
C::init();
```

Result:

```
ABA
ABC
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this, without having to redeclare and initialize my property in the child classes?

Comment: Do you really need to use static methods and properties? If you explain what it is you're actually are trying to do (what you need this for), we might be able to give you some suggestions.

Comment: Static properties, yes. I don't want the variables to be initialized with each instanciation. Thus, each instance has access to some kinds of constants, which are initialized with lazy loading.

Comment: As far as I know, there aren't really a more elegant solution than what you've already done though. There are a bunch of similar questions here on SO, but they basically boils down to the same type of workaround you have. Here's a list of similar questions here: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+inherit+static+properties+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiuv9rIk4_tAhVroosKHcCsDh8QrQIoBHoECAQQBQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have instead of scalar variable, an array containing all initialized values for each class. However it's not nice solution because it's pretty limited with static variables.

```
class A {
    static protected $v = array("A" => "A");

    static public function getV() {
        return static::$v[get_called_class()] ?? static::$v[get_class()];
    }

    static public function setV($value) {
        static::$v[get_called_class()] = $value;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's more elegant indeed, because the child class doesn't have to care about the implementation in the parent and the use of the attribute $v.